# The meaning of "Buzzword" and "Hip" in a given text

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Since I'm not from an English speaking country , I was wondering if you could help me understand the meaning of these two words in this below text : The words are "Buzzword" and "hip" . And could you please explain the meaning of the text a little bit so that I can understand what it wants to say?

> Astrobiology is arguably the trendiest buzzword in science after genomics. Like genomics, it is as hip as it is hard to define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buzzword = a word or expression from a particular subject area that has become fashionable by being used a lot, especially on television and in the newspapers:

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/buzzword)

Hip = fashionable

Buzzword came into use from 1960 onwards. Hip came into use as trendy (fashionable) word for fashionable about the same time. Both words seem a little stale now, reminding us of the 20th century.

So: “*Astrobiology* is an exciting fashionable word that is equally fashionable and indefinable.“

Comment: Except that I would agree with you that 'buzzword' and 'hip' are buzzwords that are no longer hip :-) I wonder if the passage is a little dated.